# How to take quality photos of products?

Tags: product-photography

I have a product I want to sell online but when I take a picture of it, it has some sort of a background so it never looks quite professional. What I want to be able to do is take pictures which look like [this](http://www.microsoft.com/global/en-us/news/publishingimages/images/press/2008/01-24XP-M1550RED_lg_Print.jpg).

I have experience using green screens with videos, would using a green screen by a good way of removing the background?

Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Similar: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/what-are-the-key-things-to-think-about-when-photographing-jewelry?rq=1

Comment: Another very similar question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19658/how-to-do-lighting-for-product-photography-of-scrapbooking-stuff?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This subject has been broadly discussed online. For example [here](http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/product-photography.htm) and [here](http://www.tabletopstudio.com/TTS_Product_Photography_Tips.html) , and it seems it all comes down to:

1. Using a seamless white background
2. Using enough light to eliminate shadows - two or 3 lights setups are recommended.

I have tried it, and I was able to produce good results with a single sheet of white paper (a few bucks at a hobby store) and some desk lamps. Of course the better the light the more likely you are to produce a good photo, but if you don't want to spend a lot of money, just some ikea desk lamps will do. (Use some form of diffuser on them to soften the light)

**EDIT:** I must add that with my setup I usually can get a pretty good shot in camera, but then I have to tweak it in post and lighten highlights etc, so I recommend shooting RAW if you're not.